# TinyMCE not working with multiple AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, tinymce

My page is getting loaded through Ajax. I am using tinyMCE for a few textarea on the page. It gets loaded the first time. But when I make another ajax call the tinyMCE does not work anymore and I see a normal textarea. I know I have to use execCommand and Add and Remove the editor. But it will be nice if someone can help me with where to insert it.

```js
<script>
function show(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxpage.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  $.ajax({
  url: "ajaxpage.php",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    
 tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea'
  });
    
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: it looks like you are using jQuery.ajax along with the native XMLHttpRequest. What is the reason for this?

Comment: no particular reason.

Comment: the problem is that what you are doing is a complete mess. I think, no one can tell you what exactly is wrong with you page without looking into an example, which includes the php sctipt and html. The first thing which is definitely wrong is that you are using both the XMLHttpRequest and (probably) the jQuery ajax method. You should either use jQuery.ajax or XMLHttpRequest, but not both, there is no sense to do this.

Comment: so if you provide more details (a url, or the scripts themselves here), I think, I will be able to tell you what is wrong, but here I can tell nothing